# Parsing HTML plaintext data into javascript array

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

So I have a very simple HTML page called Terms.html. Here is the output:

```
Museums, Parks, Railroads and Trains, Shopping, Theatres
```

and here is the code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body> Museums, Parks, Railroads and Trains, Shopping, Theatres </body>
</html>
```

Now, I am using jQuery $.get method to retrieve this html page:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<script>
var tags = [ "String1", "String2"];
$.get("Terms.html", function(data, status) {
    <!--  -->

    $(result).html( data );
    alert("Status: " + status);
});

</script>

<p>Search terms are: <span id="displayterms"></span></p>
<div id="result"><div>

</body>
</html>
```

What I want to do is be able to parse `Museums, Parks, Railroads and Trains, Shopping, Theatres` into individual strings and add them to my `var tags` array. Any ideas on how I can do this? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the split function: http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_split.asp

This will split on any character you choose, in this case ","

```
tags = data.split(",");
```

Comment: How can I get the string from the HTML? is data the actual plaintext or the code for the html?

Comment: @David Lounsbrough That'll do the trick. however since he already has tags in his array and wants to add you should probably do `var tags2 = data.split(,); foreach(var i =0; i < tags2.length; i++){ tags.push(tags2[i]; )}` - @user1282637 it will get the dom element (in this case, the contents of the body) and return it as a string http://api.jquery.com/get/

Comment: Don't forget to account the spaces after each comma and removal of the word and.

Comment: oh, I see you defined data as the html output. In this case you could say tagString = $(data).find("body").html();

Comment: @DavidLounsbrough and then tags = tagString.split(","); ?

Comment: @DavidLounsbrough It may be a better choice to reference split function on mdn instead of w3schools as it lacks of details and is sometimes even wrong (for example split may accept a RegExp as a parameter, which is not mentionned in w3school reference).

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
var tags = ["String1", "String2"];
var str = "Museums, Parks, Railroads and Trains, Shopping, Theatres";
arr = $.map( tags.concat(str.split(',')), function( n ) { return $.trim(n) });
console.log(arr); // Outputs the array ["String1", "String2", "Museums", "Parks", "Railroads and Trains", "Shopping", "Theatres"]
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/pkLa13zL/)**

The third line splits the `str` on the commas and then uses jQuery's .map() function to trim the whitespace.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't need to support versions of IE older than 9, you could do something like this:

```
var tags = document.body.textContent.split(',').map(
    function (s) {
        return s.trim();
    }
);
```

`document.body.textContent` gets the text in the body tag. This restricts your browser support, as IE didn't have this until version 9.

`.split(',')` takes the string and splits it into its component parts, returning an array.

`.map()` applies a function to everything in the array returned by `.split(',')`, and returns an array of the results. In this case, we use it to call `trim()` on each string in the array, to strip leading and trailing whitespace. IE didn't have the `Array.prototype.map` or `String.prototype.trim` methods until version 9, but they're easy to polyfill. It's the `textContent` thing above that's trickier.

The array returned from `map()` is then put into your `tags` variable.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of storing the contents as HTML, you could store them in a JSON data file.

An example JSON data file (places.json):

```
{
    "Names": [ "Museums", "Parks", "Railroads and Trains", "Shopping", "Theatres"]
}
```

Then, you can change your page code to:

```
<script>
var tags = [ "String1", "String2"];
$.getJSON("/places.json", function(data) {
    $(result).html(data);
    console.log(data.Names[0]); // Outputs Museums
    $.each(data.Names, function(index, value) {
        tags.push(value); // add the tag to your tags list for each item in Names
    });
});

</script>
```

This way you can store just the data you need and you won't need to parse the HTML manually.